# Python: Initializing and filling a list of lists from another list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples, enumerate

I have a list of lists in Python which contains a tuple
For eg.

```
tuple_list = 
[ [(a1,b1), (a2,b2).......(a99, b99)]
  [(c1,d1), (c2,d2).......(c99, d99)]
  .
  .
  .
  [(y1,z1), (y2,z2).......(y99, z99)]]
```

I want to initialize two list of lists  `a_list` and `b_list`

In `a_list`, I want it to have `first index` of every tuple from `tuple_list`

```
a_list = 
 [ [a1, a2.......a99]
      [c1, c2.......c99]
      .
      .
      .
      [y1, y2.......y99]]
```

and `b_list` must have `second index` of every tuple from `tuple_list`

```
 [ [b1, b2.......b99]
      [d1, d2.......d99]
      .
      .
      .
      [z1, z2.......z99]]
```

I tried this

```
a_list = [[]] * len(tuple_list )
    b_list = [[]] * len(tuple_list )

 for index, list in enumerate(tuple_list ):
        for index2,number in enumerate(list):
            a_list [index].append(number[0])
            b_list [index].append(number[1])
```

But its giving me some different answer. How do I do it?

Comment: Why aren't you appending anything to a_list?

Comment: @skott I'm sorry..edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a_list and b_list using list comprehnsion like this

```
a_list = [[t[0] for t in row] for row in tuple_list]
b_list = [[t[1] for t in row] for row in tuple_list]
```